Let $\phi : A \to B$ be a surjective $*$-homomorphism of star algebras, is there any good notion of "normal bundle of $B$ in $A$"?
Let $\phi : A \to B$ be a surjective $*$-homomorphism of star algebras (maybe more restricted kind of star algebra), is there any good notion of "normal bundle of $B$  in $A$"? By a "good" notion, I mean if when $A$ is $C^\infty(M)$, and $B$ is $C^\infty(N)$ for two manifolds $M$ and $N$, and $\phi$ is induced from a smooth embedding, the algebraically defined normal bundle should reduce to the ordinary normal bundle of $N$ in $M$.
According to the Serre–Swan theorem, vector bundles over $M$ are equivalent to projective modules over $C(M)$, I guess we should define a particular kind of projective module over $B$? Is there already any research or references for this?

If I understand correctly, the notion of normal bundle depends on Riemannian structure, so this corresponds to additional structure that is needed on your algebras $A$ and $B$. (The dictionary between commutative Cstar algebras and topological spaces does not see the metric structure unless one introduces extra structure on those Cstar algebras.)

yes, my question should be under what kind of additional structure we can define the normal bundle.

it should be defined for not necessarily commutative algebras with additional structure and generalize the manifold case.

Before turning to noncommutative submanifolds in the literature, it's worth remembering that there are three basic approaches for equipping a $\ast$-algebra $A$ with the structure of a 'noncommutative manifold' in noncommutative geometry à la Connes.

Following Dubois-Violette, you generalize vector fields in terms of $\ast$-derivations of $A$.
Following Woronowicz, you generalize exterior calculus in terms of a $\ast$-differential graded algebra $(\Omega_A,d)$ over $\Omega^0 = A$.
Following Connes, you generalize Dirac-type operators (and the attendant Clifford action of $1$-forms) in terms of a spectral triple $(A,H,D)$.

Now, there's been relatively little work so far on noncommutative submanifolds, most of which uses the first approach. None of the three approaches readily yields a noncommutative normal bundle in keeping with the Serre–Swan philosophy, but the second approach (which, to my knowledge, has only been applied to noncommutative submanifolds by Nguyen–Schenkel) can yield a noncommutative conormal bundle as follows.
Anyhow, an embedding of compact smooth manifolds $\phi : X \to Y$ yields the canonical short exact sequence of $C^\infty(X)$-bimodules
$$
 0 \to \Gamma(N^\ast X) \to \Gamma(\phi^\ast T^\ast Y) \xrightarrow{(D\phi)^t} \Omega^1(X) \to 0,
$$
where $N^\ast X := \ker((D\phi)^t: \phi^\ast T^\ast Y \to T^\ast X)$ is the conormal bundle of the embedding and where $$\Gamma(\phi^\ast T^\ast Y) \cong C^\infty(X) \otimes_{C^\infty(Y)} \Omega^1(Y) \otimes_{C^\infty(Y)} C^\infty(X).$$
This is the picture one can try to generalize in the second approach, at least at the level of first-order differential calculi.
So, let $(A;\Omega^1_A,d_A)$ and $(B;\Omega^1_B,d_B)$ be unital $\ast$-algebras equipped with first-order $\ast$-differential calculi (see, e.g., section 1.1 of the book of Beggs–Majid). Suppose that $\phi : A \to B$ is a surjective $\ast$-homomorphism that is differentiable in the sense that $a_1 d_A(a_2) \mapsto \phi(a_1) d_B(\phi(a_2))$ yields a well-defined map $\phi_\ast : \Omega^1_A \to \Omega^1_B$. Then $\phi_\ast$ induces a surjective morphism of $B$-bimodules $B \otimes_A \Omega^1_A \otimes_A B \to \Omega^1_B$,
whose kernel $N^1_B$, which is often finitely-generated projective as both a left and right $B$-module, is your candidate noncommutative conormal bundle; thus you get the straightforward noncommutative generalization $$0 \to N^1_B \to B \otimes_A \Omega^1_A \otimes_A B \to \Omega^1_B \to 0$$ of the commutative short exact sequence above. Nguyen–Schenkel work with the case where $(\Omega^1_B,d_B)$ is induced by $(\Omega^1_A,d_A)$ and $N^1_B$ is freely generated as both a left and right $B$-module by a central element $\nu$, which you can think of as a normal $1$-form for the noncommutative hypersurface $(A;\Omega^1_A,d_A)$ in $(B;\Omega^1_B,d_B)$. From there, they are able to induce various noncommutative Riemannian structures on the noncommutative hypersurface $(B;\Omega^1_B,d_B)$ from corresponding structures on the noncommutative ambient space $(A;\Omega^1_A,d_A)$.
